# Trying to print the total using rollup query

Tags: sql

I am executing a query then using the output to generate excel file using C#, so I need the query to print the total of each column at the end of it. but when I list the days asc to align them as:

- 1-1-2024
- 2-1-2024
- .
- .
- 23/1/2024

The query is printing the total at the very beginning of the result which is not the goal.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
    CONVERT(date, AttemptDateTime) AS [Day], 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerID LIKE '8' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Telecom Namibia], 
    CAST((SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerID LIKE '8' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) + 
    SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerID Like '6' AND CGPN LIKE '2646%' OR CGPN LIKE '2642646%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END)) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Telecom Namibia - Combined], 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerID LIKE '21' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Telecom Namibia International], 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerID Like '6' AND CGPN NOT LIKE '2646%' AND CGPN NOT LIKE '264821%' AND CGPN NOT LIKE '2642646%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [TN Mobile - Mobile], 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerID Like '6' AND CGPN LIKE '264821%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [TN Mobile - Focus Telecom], 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerID Like '6' AND CGPN LIKE '2646%' OR CGPN LIKE '2642646%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Others], 
    CAST((SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerID Like '6' AND CGPN NOT LIKE '2646%' AND CGPN NOT LIKE '264821%' AND CGPN NOT LIKE '2642646%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerID Like '6' AND CGPN LIKE '264821%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerID Like '6' AND CGPN LIKE '2646%' OR CGPN LIKE '2642646%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END)) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [TN Mobile - Combined], 
    CAST(SUM(DurationInSeconds/60.0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Total Duration (min)] 
FROM 
    [ToneV2_CDR].[TOneWhS_CDR].[BillingCDR_Main] 
WHERE 
    AttemptDateTime >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
    AND AttemptDateTime < GETDATE() 
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(date, AttemptDateTime) WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY 
    [Day] ASC;


SET NOCOUNT ON; 

SELECT 
    CONVERT(date, AttemptDateTime) AS [Day], 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN SupplierID LIKE '8' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Telecom Namibia], 
    CAST((SUM(CASE WHEN SupplierID LIKE '8' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN SupplierID LIKE '6' AND CDPN NOT LIKE '26485%' AND CDPN NOT LIKE '264821%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END)) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Telecom Namibia - Combined], 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN SupplierID LIKE '6' AND CDPN LIKE '26485%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [TN Mobile - Mobile], 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN SupplierID LIKE '6' AND CDPN LIKE '264821%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [TN Mobile - Focus Telecom], 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN SupplierID LIKE '6' AND CDPN NOT LIKE '26485%' AND CDPN NOT LIKE '264821%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Others], 
    CAST((SUM(CASE WHEN SupplierID LIKE '6' AND CDPN LIKE '26485%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN SupplierID LIKE '6' AND CDPN LIKE '264821%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END) + 
SUM(CASE WHEN SupplierID LIKE '6' AND CDPN NOT LIKE '26485%' AND CDPN NOT LIKE '264821%' THEN DurationInSeconds/60.0 ELSE 0 END)) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [TN Mobile - Combined], 
    CAST(SUM(DurationInSeconds/60.0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Total Duration (min)] 
FROM 
    [ToneV2_CDR].[TOneWhS_CDR].[BillingCDR_Main] 
WHERE 
    AttemptDateTime >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
    AND AttemptDateTime < GETDATE() 
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(date, AttemptDateTime) WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY 
    [Day] ASC;
```

Please provide guidance or suggestion if possible.